# How to let UIButton is highlighted when I touch outside to inside bound?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I touch outside bound of UIButton then drag inside the UIButton. The state is not highlight.

How can I set the UIButton is detect highlighted, when my finger just touch inside bound of UIButton?

For Example: make a piano app, when I touch a note and drag left or right , it not only the first sound, it detect all sound I touched.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
  UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
  myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter; //this method is fired when user touches the button and drags it from inside the bounds of the button.

-(IBAction)myFunction:sender(id){
    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     myButton.highlighted = YES;
     [self checkForHighlight];
}

-(void)checkForHighlight {
   if(myButton.highlighted){
     myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
   }
```

You need to declare the UIButton *myButton as a static variable, so that all methods of the VC can access it.

Comment: thank you.
But I don't need the IBAction.  I use TouchDragEnter can't let the button highlighted when drag outside to inside the bound. It just sending a action , but I need the button state is highlighted